# How to build an array using form values in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material, typescript2.0

I have the function in the component as below:

```
updateInfo(info: NgForm) {
    const changedValues = Object.keys(info.controls)
      .filter(key => info.controls[key].dirty === true)
      .map(key => {
        return { control: key, value: info.controls[key].value }
      });
    console.log(changedValues);
}
```

This function emits the changes form values, but now I want to build an array using `changedValues` as below:

{
firstName: "john", 
lastName: "sam"
}

How could I implement it?

**Edit**: currently I'm getting like this in the console log

```
[
{firstName: "john"},
{lastName: "sam"}
]
```

Comment: Please show the data as before (what you have now) and after (what you want to have as an array) so that we understand what format you need.

Comment: Please see me edit above. I want the output like this { firstName: "john", lastName: "sam" }

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `map` because that returns an array. Instead use `forEach` and add the items to your object:

```
updateInfo(info: NgForm) {
  const changedValues = {};
  Object.keys(info.controls).forEach(key => {
    if (info.controls[key].dirty) { 
      changedValues[key] = info.controls[key].value;
    }
  });
  console.log(changedValues);
}
```